# How to send port from server in desktop to client in client?

Tags: java, android, tcp

I've a application client in Android and server in desktop
Server port input from keyboard, how to send port to client in Android. Sorry, I come from Viet Nam, so English bad.

This is client

```
try {
                    Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.101", 1111);
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(message);
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                    client.close();                         
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This is server

```
try {
                    ss = new ServerSocket(3333);
                    while(true){
                        Socket client = ss.accept();
                        DataInputStream dis =  new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()); 
                        String request = dis.readUTF();

                        dis.close();
                        client.close();

                    }
                } catch (IOException | AWTException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Port server = 3333
how get port from server for client

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You decide what port number you're going to use and hardware it in both server and client. Otherwise you have an infinitely recursive problem: what port do I use to send the port over?